# Arrangement of 9 digits in a 3×3 grid

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

**Question**

Consider a $3\times 3$ grid with the first $9$  positive integers placed in the grid. Take the greatest integer in each row and let $r$ be the smallest of those numbers. Take the smallest integer in each column and let $c$ be the greatest of those numbers.

- a) True or false: Regardless of the arrangement of the numbers, $r\leq c$  always. Give explanation if true, or a counterexample if false.
- b) How many arrangements are there such that $r\leq c\leq 4$ ?

**Attempt**

I have got "*no*" as an answer for part a) and 306 as an answer for b) but as there is no official answer to this problem (in the source where I have collected it from) can anyone contradict or verify my solution.

Comment: As it is usually said: show your work. You are not doing this problem to calculate the result (someone has already done it, e.g. the maker of the problem): you are doing it to demonstrate your logical/mathematical thinking, and *that* is what we should scrutinise here. How did you arrive to the answers “no” and “306”? In particular, have you got a counterexample in (a)?

Comment: Even if you cannot solve a problem completely, it is helpful to tackle a simplified version and present that to show how far you got in solving.  For example, tackle the arrangements (if any) where $r=c$.  Is it possible?  How many such arrangements are there?

Comment: If you have a counter-example for (a), then you don't need us to verify it. As for (b), notice that permuting either the rows or the columns of the grid does not change the values of $r$ or $c$. Further, given a particular grid, any combination of a permutation of rows and one of columns produces a unique new grid. There are $36$ combinations of permuting rows and permuting columns. So any grid with $r \le c \le 4$ comes in a group of $36$ such solutions. Thus $36$ should divide the answer for (b).